# How to send emails to filtered attribute groups

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contact, attribute-group, data-designer

I used the Data Designer to link Contacts to some other information in a few Data Extensions. The links were done by primary key (1:1), either Subscriber Key or Email Address (both unique to contact). This created an Attribute Group.

Let's say it's something like the below:

```
Contact -> (Email Address) -> FlagA
        -> (Subscriber Key) -> FlagB
```

where FlagA and FlagB are Data Extensions with `(Email Address, FlagA)` and `(Subscriber Key, FlagB)`.

Now, I want to filter `Email Address, FlagA = a, FlagB = b` into a data extension so I can send an email to this segment of my users. I'm having a hard time creating a data extension off an Attribute Group.

How do I send an email to this filtered attribute group? I may be severely misunderstanding linked Data Extensions, but this should be doable as [per the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_designer.htm&type=5):

> For example, you can use the email address from a contact record to link to another data extension that contains product and shipping information. The contact record can then draw on any information uploaded to the product and shipping information data extension without changing the information in the contact record. That link allows you to create filters based on whether that email address links to a specific product order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking in Contact builder makes the fields available in Journey Builder (limits apply in 1:n scenarios).
So you could use filters / decision splits with the data after the linkage, but your send must be through JB.

If you want to do a "simple send", then I recommend looking into data relationships in Email Studio, which makes point & click filters accessible over related data extensions. Does not require contact builder.

Last but not least you can write an SQL Query activity to combine data from several sources and run it via Automation Studio to create a new Data extension with all your values, and send to that one. Also does not require contact builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up data relationships directly in Email Studio.

> A data relationship in Email Studio specifies that a column in one
>   data extension contains the same kind of information as a column in
>   another data extension or in a subscriber attribute. Use a data
>   relationship to relate two data extensions based on a common column
>   contained in both data extensions. You can then apply a filter to the
>   two data extensions and create a new segment of data.

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_relationships.htm&type=5

Comment: This is what I did in the end